# select next and prev id order not logical

Tags: mysql, select

Is it possible to select the next row from the following table?

```
Table foo
Values:
312
911
128 <-- prev
389 <-- current
124 <-- next
993
213
```

I am not sure how to select on this cause the numbers aren't in order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't specify an order then the DB engine will not order the data at all. So whatever you try to select after a specific record needs to be ordered.

Comment: There is no 'natural' order? Like first comes etc? (basically the order they are inserted)

Comment: No, the order could be different on each select you fire.

Comment: @jurgen That's not right, ordering won't differ for the same select (w/o order by) every time.

Comment: @MarcellFülöp: It **could** but it does not have to. You just can't **rely** on a specific order.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible using MySQL [HANDLER](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/handler.html) syntax. The documentation says it only works with the `MyISAM` engine though:

> "The third HANDLER ... READ syntax fetches a row from the table in
>   natural row order"
>
> Natural row order is the order in which rows are stored in a MyISAM
>   table data file.

Assume the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE `a` (
  `a_col` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `d_col` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `c_col` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`a_col`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

with the following data:

```
mysql> select * from a;
+-------+---------------------+-----------+
| a_col | d_col               | c_col     |
+-------+---------------------+-----------+
|     0 | 2013-11-20 15:25:55 | nürnberg  |
|     3 | 2013-11-11 00:00:00 | NULL      |
|     4 | 2013-11-21 12:32:56 | adsf      |
|    11 | 2013-11-21 12:33:04 | adsf      |
|    17 | 2013-11-21 12:32:46 | adsf      |
|    30 | 2013-11-21 12:33:11 | adsf      |
|   861 | 2013-11-21 12:33:01 | adsf      |
+-------+---------------------+-----------+
```

Now you can open a handler:

```
mysql> handler a open;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

---

Read an arbitrary row:

```
mysql> handler a read `PRIMARY` = (4);
+-------+---------------------+-------+
| a_col | d_col               | c_col |
+-------+---------------------+-------+
|     4 | 2013-11-21 12:32:56 | adsf  |
+-------+---------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

---

Read the row that is next to previously read by natural order:

```
mysql> handler a read `PRIMARY` NEXT;
+-------+---------------------+-------+
| a_col | d_col               | c_col |
+-------+---------------------+-------+
|    11 | 2013-11-21 12:33:04 | adsf  |
+-------+---------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)
```

---

And so on:

```
mysql> handler a read `PRIMARY` NEXT;
+-------+---------------------+-------+
| a_col | d_col               | c_col |
+-------+---------------------+-------+
|    17 | 2013-11-21 12:32:46 | adsf  |
+-------+---------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```